# Weird Unity Collision Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, rigid-bodies

I'm making a twin-stick, sneaking game where you can grab guards. Every time I collide with the wall, while holding a guard, my character will bounce off the wall and slide a bit.

[image]

[image: Player's Rigidbody]

I found out I could get rid of this issue by setting the Player's Drag to a higher value. However that leaves the Player stuck at a single y-axis, & they can't go up stairs.

Does anyone know how I can fix this bouncy issue while also not fixing the Player's y-axis?

Comment: I want the player to push off the wall to where both don't touch. It'd be bad to have bug like this push me out of cover.

Comment: May you provide more infomation, how does the character move? physic materials and colliders.. properties, is there any other scripts affect the collision? and why lock the rotation? I have no idea with only 2 pictures.

Comment: I use Rigidbody's MovePosition function to move the player. I have script that alters the controls if the player is against a wall, but it won't effect the player if they're holding a guard. Rotation is handled by both left and right stick. I force the player to face the direction they're moving towards with the left stick, while the right stick will rotate the player to face any direction the player moves the stick towards.